# check remote wmi and remote registry

Tags: powershell

I am using the below code snippet in my script to check if Remote WMI and Remote Registry is working. Could you please help me if this is the right way to do it and if there is a better way of checking if remote WMI and Remote Registry is working.

```
#WMI
GWMI -Query "Select * from Win32_PingStatus where Address = '$server'" -Credential $altcreds -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#REMOTE REGISTRY
get-wmiobject -list "StdRegProv" -namespace root\default -computername $server -credential $altcreds -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Thanks!

Comment: If it works there is not wrong way really. If it was me I would do one line like this `(get-wmiobject win32_service -filter "name='RemoteRegistry'" -ComputerName $server).State`. Using WMI checks if it is enabled and the to check the service state. To get a response of "started" means both WMI remoting is working and the the service is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first check determines if `$server` responds to `ping` requests. That does not tell you anything about its accessibility via WMI.

The second check determines if the `StdRegProv` WMI class on the remote host is accessible. That does not tell you anything about the status of the `RemoteRegistry` service.

If you want to check the state of the `RemoteRegistry` Service on a remote host (and start it in case it's not running) you could do something like this:

```psh
$svc = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Computer $server `
         -Filter "Name='RemoteRegistry'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
         -Credential $altcreds

if (-not $svc) {
  "Cannot connect to $server."
  exit 1
}

if ($svc.State -eq 'Stopped') { $svc.StartService() }
```

or (more PoSh) like this:

```psh
Invoke-Command -Computer $server -ScriptBlock {
  Get-Service 'RemoteRegistry' | ? { $_.State -eq 'Stopped' } | Start-Service
} -Credential $altcreds
```

---

**Edit:** To test the accessibility of a remote registry or WMI service you could do something like this:

```psh
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($hive, $server)
$svc = Get-WmiObject -List -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $server
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

if ($reg) {
  "Access to registry on $server succeeded."
} else {
  "Cannot access registry on $server."
}

if ($svc) {
  "Access to WMI on $server succeeded."
} else {
  "Cannot access WMI on $server."
}
```

Or, if you're interested in some error information, something like this:

```psh
try {
  $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($hive, $server)
} catch {
  "Cannot access registry on {0}. Error: {1:x}" -f $server, $_.Exception.HResult
}

try {
  $svc = Get-WmiObject -List -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $server `
           -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
  "Cannot access WMI on {0}. Error: {1:x}" -f $server, $_.Exception.HResult
}
```

**Edit2:** According to an answer in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d9aa649d-7713-427c-a218-8b25462b1da2) you can authenticate remote registry access by using the [`Impersonation`](http://poshcode.org/5371) module:

```psh
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Import-Module Impersonation
Push-ImpersonationContext $cred
try {
  $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($hive, $server)
} catch {
  "Cannot access registry on {0}. Error: {1:x}" -f $server, $_.Exception.HResult
}
Pop-ImpersonationContext
```

I haven't tested this, though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't want to check the status of the Remote Registry service. I would like to check if I can remotely access the remote registry of a remote computer. Similarly, I would like to check if the WMI is working on the remote computer. Any suggestions please!!

Comment: Thank you! However, for the Remote Registry check. How can I pass credentials and perform the registry check? Is there a way like using the -Credential parameter?